# UITableViewCell - Can I show the 'Delete' button programatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview

When a user swipes on a cell, it's trivial to enable the swipe to delete button appearing. However, I'd like to show this delete button when a different event happens. Is this possible?

Note that adding my own delete button appear would also be trivial, but for several reasons I'd like to use Apple's - localisation, consistency across upcoming iOS versions, etc.

Comment: Is setting the table view into editing mode and implementing `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Wain No sorry, this shows a red minus sign which you need to tap before seeing the delete button - I'd like to skip this step.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure there is a way to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL:DR;  No. this event fires in response to a gesture baked into the UITableViewDelegate protocol, and you can't call it manually. You'll have to roll your own.

`tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` is your first chance to catch the event that launches Apple's pre-built cell editing modes (assuming the tableView's dataSource has `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` configured...) and it has been hardwired into a swipe gesture recognized by the tableView itself.

Everything in between the tableView catching this UISwipeGesture and calling `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` is buried inside of the private API of a UITableView.

While many of us do bastardize these "editing" views to launch other things in our apps without having to subclass UITableViewCell, getting that kind of an accessory view to show up inside your cell in response to something more than a just swipe gestures is the perfect use-case for subclassing.